# how to override setTimeOut function in javascript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor plugin in grails.
I have this function in ckeditor.js

```
setTimeout(function(){var u=t.getInputElement();
    u&&u.$.focus();
},0)
```

---

```
setTimeout(function(){var u=t.getInputElement();
    if(u){ 
    u.$.focus();
    u.$.select();}},0)
```

I need to change time out from 0 to say 10000. 
Now the problem is I that I have asked not to touch ckeditor.js file since it is plugin file and it is used at many places.
So I should make changes in some local file which imports ckeditor.js.

So how should I override this function or do something else to change the value of timeout function

Comment: if the setTimeout is not assigned to a variable, you can't do that

Comment: In order to override the `setTimeout()` timer, you need the return value from the original call. This will not be possible without changing the ckeditor.js file.

Comment: I have gone through ckeditor api and there is one method    CKEDITOR.tools.setTimeout(
    function()
    {
        alert( 'Executed after 2 seconds' );
    },
    2000 );                                                                      but I am not sure how it will work if I add this in local js file. Will it override the function?

Answer (score 0):

create a new javascript file and write the following method

```
  (function() {
    var oldsetTimeout = setTimeout;
    setTimeout = extendedsetTimeout;
    function extendedsetTimeout() {
       setTimeout();//call old method
       doSomething();
    }
 })();
```

Comment: I am getting Error: Object doesn't support this action on setTimeout = extendedsetTimeout; Also how will this logic change timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Good advice: debug source files, not built and minified version...

You most likely mean [these lines](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/dialogui/plugin.js#L905-L913). Just override `CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.textInput.prototype.focus` function with your own one and that's it.

Comment: So I should add the lines mentioned by you and change timeout from 0 to whatever I need and this should delay the focus() execute time wherever setTimeout is used, right?